# unable to load image using Javascript in IE 6

Tags: javascript, image-processing, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to set source for Img tag using Javascript at button click. The problem which i m facing is that the I cannot see the Image in IE 6 but it works in FireFox. I browsed and tried few solutions like load the image in page load(Document load) itself or set a timer, but  nothing works consistently. This problem also not consistent so unable to find the exact solution. the code goes here-

```
<li> <a id="lnk1" runat="server">
<img class="each_idea_icon" alt="" runat="server" id="imgAs" idea="images"  />                          
</a>
</li>

//on button client click
var imgAs = $('#<%=imgAs.ClientID %>');
imgAs.attr("src", "../../Common/Images/EN/ABC.png");
```

Can somebody tell me wat could be the issue. It works perfectly in IE. I have removed ">" or "<" so code can be visible.

by default in server side i set the image src.

Comment: Hmm, you didn't copy&paste your code correctly (I hope =p)

Comment: You can format it as code by putting four spaces before the line.

Comment: Can you try `document.getElementById('...').src = '...');` and see if that works?

Comment: (OT) Is your page *really* an XHTML page, served as XML? If not, you're better off using HTML syntax. More here: http://www.w3.org/International/articles/serving-xhtml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had the same problem and the below code fixed it:

```
var imgAs = $('#<%=imgAs.ClientID %>');
var imgParent = img.parentNode;

imgParent.innerHTML = "<img src='/_layouts/images/minus.gif' id='" + img.id + "' alt='" + img.alt + "'></img>";
```

I assigned the HTML string to `innerHTML` of its parent element.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
imgAs.setAttribute ( "src" , "../../Common/Images/EN/ABC.png" );
```

See

[element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SetAttribute)

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. This solution didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it first to a blank/clear gif or image file?  Sometimes it has a hard time setting the img src, if it did not have an image initially.

Answer (score 0):

I beleve i know what is your problem , for some reason when u use 
`<img ... />` 
insted of 
`<img ..>   </img>` 
in some cases it does not work

Comment: if i don't set my image throgh server side-vb.net (as i said while page load i set it by default) then it works perfectly.

Comment: so is there any problem tht if we set it through server side and then try to set using client side(javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Try an image that is not a png, ie6 and png's never played nicely. You need some ie specific code to get them to work properly.